# MPMoviePlayerViewController hanging at loading screen

Tags: ios, xcode, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

I  have code that records the screen in my app, and then I want to be able to play it back.  I have gotten so far as to get to the black loading screen with the rewind, play and fast forward buttons, but it hangs at loading without playing anything.

This code plays the clip:

-(IBAction)playMovie:(id)sender
{

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *movieViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:locationOfVideoURL];
movieViewController.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:movieViewController];
```

}

I believe the problem has something to do with the locationOfVideoURL variable.  I am able to print it and it seems like it SHOULD work.

Here it is printed out:

file://localhost/Users/myusername/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.1/Applications/[left out, personal info]/Documents/Videoclip.mp4

Any ideas? Any help would be greatly appreciated! thank you

EDIT: Location of video clip:

```
      NSString *outputPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/%@",         [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0], @"Videoclip.mp4"];

      NSURL *outputURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:outputPath];
      NSLog(@"Completed recording, file is stored at:  %@", outputURL);
```

Comment: Is this video in the docs directory, or the app bundle?

Comment: I'm not sure...can you tell me? (see the first post...its an edit at the bottom)

Is it the....documents directory?

Comment: Do you have any code that explicitly copies it into the documents directory?

Comment: I used this tutorial to capture the screen:

http://codethink.no-ip.org/wordpress/archives/673

I don't think i explicitly copy it into the document directory though.

Comment: The movie playing screen comes up (the timeline, done button, ect.) but hangs at loading without playing the movie.  If I can copy the video into the pictures album or whatever, and then load it from there, that would be ideal.  I will keep searching, but if anyone knows a good tutorial or has code to do this, it would be greatly appreciated.